# how to store and retrieve a jpg image in oracle database using BLOB datatype in java

Tags: java, database, servlets

I've tried the following code to retrieve an image stored in the oracle database with BLOB datatype. Upon running it in apace tomcat7 server i could only see an image icon(may be a broken image) but not an image. When I tried to open the image icon it got downloaded. I opened the downloaded image using picasa but it displayed "invalid image". 
PLEASE try solving my problem....!!

```
public class RetrieveInkblot extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Blob photo = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String query = "select img from inkblots where  bid = 23";
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system", "manager");
            out.println("Connection");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


            if (rs == null) {
                out.print("null except");
            } else if (rs.next()) {
                photo = rs.getBlob(1);

            } else {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                out.println("<html><head><title>Person Photo</title></head>");
                out.println("<body><h1>No photo found for id= 001 </h1></body></html>");
                return;
            }
            byte[] imgData = photo.getBytes(1, (int) photo.length());
            response.setContentType("image/jpg");
            OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
            o.write(imgData);
            o.flush();
            o.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            out.println("<html><head><title>Error: Person Photo</title></head>");
            out.println("<body><h1>Error=" + e.getMessage() + "</h1></body></html>");
            return;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Don't store image in the database. Just store the image path in database.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line:

```
byte[] imgData = photo.getBytes(1,(int)photo.length());
```

Note that java starts counting by 0, so change it to this line:

```
byte[] imgData = photo.getBytes(0,(int)photo.length());
```

If this gives you a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you also need to decrement `photo.length()`:

```
byte[] imgData = photo.getBytes(0,(int)photo.length()-1);
```

By the way I wouldn't save the picture in the database, I would either write the image into your server and write the url into database, or encode the image with base64 witch is easier to read back.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But saving the image into server isn't my requirement, i have to save the image in the database.And yeah, i have tried already byte[] imgData = photo.getBytes(0,(int)photo.length()-1); but that didn't made any difference.

Comment: @user3888255 Then your image seems defect, try inserting an image that you are sure is correct (so other programs like your browser can display without your server), make sure the image data in your database is also displayable, and try again